# Codeblocks v. 13.12 error after adding class

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, freeglut, devil

Using C++ in codeblocks v. 13.12 every time I add a new class and try to build and run it gives me an undefined reference to winmain@16.  After closing and opening codeblocks it works fine and the class files stay there but I would rather not have to restart codeblocks everytime I add a new class.  I am using freeglut, opengl and devil.

[picture](http://puu.sh/cIYAU/0a15f17478.png)

And this is NOT like one of the other undefined reference problems with not linking properly.

EDIT:
I reinstalled an earlier version(12.11) and it is working fine so I am just going to use it instead

[downloads for 12.11](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/12.11/)

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help but I don't feel like you read my question completely.  I said it only gives me the undefined reference after I have created a class, but it works fine again after restarting codeblocks.  Neither of those two links have my same problem

Comment: Yes, this is new to the new version of codeblocks. I am also looking for this answer.